# Vaadin 24 login always redirects to root url

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin

I'm developing an application in Vaadin 24. I have a login page that uses the default login component. Using this login, I'd like to redirect the use to the url the login page was called from but after a login I'm always redirected to the root url.

Here is my security configuration. I assume that I have to pass some kind of redirect header since the login page does not know where the original request is coming from. But I can't find any source on how to do this.

Hope you can help me out.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Security Config set...");
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers(
                        AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/icons/*.png"),
                        AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/img/*.png")
                        ).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                        AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/login*")
                        ).permitAll()
                )
                .formLogin(formLogin -> 
                    formLogin.successHandler(new VaadinSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
                ));
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: In vaadin 24, you shouldn't need to call. the http.formLogin method, the call to setLoginView(http, LoginView.class); should be enough and it enables the redirection behavior you desire. What happens if you comment out the whole http.authorizeHttpRequests(...) code? I tried it locally and it just works.

Comment: When I comment out the entire authrizeHttpRequests, my images are no longer visible, so at least the first requestMatchers() are required. Uncommenting the second requestMatchers() and the formLogin() results in the behavior I described. The user is always redirected to the root url.

Comment: when I copy and paste your code as is, I don't get the behavior you are experiencing. I'm using vaadin 24.3.1. What is your version?

Answer (score 0):

As brunovianarezende suggested, removing the call to `formLogin()` fixed the misleading redirects.

But my problem remains: I am in view A, I click a login button, I am redirected to the login page, I login and I am redirected to /. But I want to Go back to A.

I guess this does not work as suggested because view A is not secured and accessible to everybody so IT does not automatically redirect me to the login view.

Any ideas how I can solve this easily?